# Dynamic links is not working properly in multiple applications

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

The problem I'm facing is as follows.
I have 6 apps added in firebase (ios and android). I created a subdomain for deep links for these apps. So far, I've used the apple-app-site-association file generated by default, but I discovered the following problem on iOS, that when I had both of my applications installed at the same time, it was because the path values ​​in this json file were empty, the dynamic link opened the first app in order in that file.

Just mention if i only had one application installed dynamic links worked properly.

After researching, I found a solution that suggested overwriting the apple-app-site-association file, so on my server, I created a firebase environment, thanks to which I could deploy this file. Unfortunately, after many attempts to configure the firebase.json file, when clicking on the deeplink, the index.html of the firebase project opens.

My **firebase.json** file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|css|js)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31536000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "404.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=300"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
        "destination": "/apple-app-site-association"
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When i set "appAssociation": "AUTO" => "NONE" i get this error:

[image: Subdomain not connected properly]

my **apple-app-site-association** with censored devID:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"com.masterofcity.newyork","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]},{"appID":"com.masterofcity.rome","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]},{"appID":"com.masterofcity.london","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]},{"appID":"com.masterofcity.paris","paths":["NOT /_/*","/shareEventParis/*","/joinGameParis/*"]},{"appID":"com.masterofcity.warsaw","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]},{"appID":"com.masterofcity.cracow","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

My custom links look like that in Firebase Panel:
[image: List of custom links]

I need to create more (2 for each application, but i don't need them for testing). I have indicated in these links their behavior, what to do when the user does not have the application installed, etc. but unfortunately after deploying firebase hosting, my dynamic link opens index.html